# react js Axios 401 Unauthorized although i have my Bearer String correct

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I have a deleteUser API that deletes a user from my MySql Database.
my API is working perfectly on postman. nut when i call my api from my react app it returns an error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

---this is my delete request---

```
const handleRowDelete = (oldData, resolve) => {
    axios
      .post("/deleteUser/" + oldData.userId, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        window.location.reload(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setErrorMessages(["Update failed! Server error"]);
        setIserror(true);
        resolve();
      });
  };
```

and even more i have un updateUser API that im also calling in the same component and it working perfectly

---this is the update api---

```
axios
        .post("/updateUser/" + newData.userId, newData, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          window.location.reload(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setErrorMessages(["Update failed! Server error"]);
          setIserror(true);
          resolve();
        });
    } else {
      setErrorMessages(errorList);
      setIserror(true);
      resolve();
    }
```

its exactly the same but the delete api is not working i cant figure out why.(401 unauthorized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass your headers as the second argument to `axios.post`, but actually it should be third argument. Second argument is `data`.

```
    axios.post(
        "/deleteUser/" + oldData.userId,
        {}, // add empty object or null here as second argument
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      })
```

Also, if you can modify your API then it would be better to use `DELETE` method for user deletion, not `POST`. (and then your code would work because `axios.delete` accepts headers as second argument)